# phpMyAdmin - Error Permisos incorrectos

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, apache2

mi problema es el siguiente: Lo que pasa es que tengo instalado phpmyadmin en ubuntu 19.10 todo estaba funcionando bien hasta que a la carpeta que contiene la configuracion del mismo se encuentra en var/www/html aca adentro tengo mis codigos php de mi pagina y para mayor comidad mia para agregar y editar los mismo le di permisos totales con el comando chmod -R 777 /var/www/html por lo que afecto tambien a la carpeta de phpmyadmin y al querer entrar por la web al mismo me tira el error:

phpMyAdmin - Error

Permisos incorrectos en el archivo de configuración ¡cualquiera no debería poder modificarlo!

nesecito revertir estos permisos que le di a la carpeta y no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Intentaste desinstalar tu phpmyadmin, y volver a instalarlo?

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge phpmyadmin

sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

No afecta a su base de datos, ni usuarios. y tendrás una versión actualizada.

Comment: Hola ya pude solucionarlo sin necesidad de desinstalar de la siguiente forma.
primero le doy todos los permisos a la carpeta entera:
chmod -R 777  /var/www/html
luego vuelvo a  asignarle el grupo y usuario con el que opera en apache 2 que generalmente es www:data pero solo a la carpeta phpMyAdmin asi :
sudo chown -R :www-data  /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin
y por ultimo le soy los permisos que requiere para funcionar:
chmod -R 774  /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin

Comment: Me doy cuenta que el directorio y subdirectorios de phpmyadmin cuentan con permisos 755 y los archivos 644. Para tu computador de desarrollo puedes usar un directorio entero y archivos con permisos 774, pero en un servidor se expone como riesgo de seguridad.